# Need MySQL REGEXP query to ignore period at the end of a sentence

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have built a search for books. Here is a query that searches through the text and returns matching results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vm.volume_name,vm.recno AS vmid,bk.book_name
       ,bk.recno AS bid,vs.recno,vs.chapter,vs.verse,vs.text 
FROM verses vs 
LEFT JOIN books bk ON bk.recno=vs.book 
LEFT JOIN volumes vm ON bk.volumeid=vm.recno 
WHERE vs.text regexp "(^|[[:space:]])jesus wept([[:space:]]|$)" 
AND vm.recno IN(1,3,4,5)
```

Here is the problem. If someone searches for "Jesus wept" they get 0 records. If they search for "Jesus wept." (period added) they get a result.

How can I change this query to ignore periods at, say, the end of a sentence, when the word they are searching is at the end of a sentence?

I need to ignore the dot and find only the word. The dot is irrelevant to the search.

Comment: Did you try to simply remove dots from the search query?

Comment: The problem is reversed. If I remove the period, I get no results. If I include the period, I get a result. The query must be searching through the text fields and finding "wept." and seeing the period as part of the word, instead of just the word only.

Comment: Note that `(^|[[:space:]])jesus wept([[:space:]]|$)` matches `jesus wept` only in between whitespace and start/end of string. It is not quite clear now what could go wrong with a dot.

Comment: I totally agree and have never experienced this before, but it is definitely happening.


SELECT DISTINCT vm.volume_name,vm.recno AS vmid,bk.book_name,bk.recno AS bid,vs.recno,vs.chapter,vs.verse,vs.text FROM verses vs LEFT JOIN books bk ON bk.recno=vs.book LEFT JOIN volumes vm ON bk.volumeid=vm.recno WHERE vs.text regexp "(^|[[:space:]])jesus wept([[:space:]]|$)" AND vm.recno IN(1,3,4,5)
Verses Found: 0

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT vm.volume_name,vm.recno AS vmid,bk.book_name,bk.recno AS bid,vs.recno,vs.chapter,vs.verse,vs.text FROM verses vs LEFT JOIN books bk ON bk.recno=vs.book LEFT JOIN volumes vm ON bk.volumeid=vm.recno WHERE vs.text regexp "(^|[[:space:]])jesus wept.([[:space:]]|$)" AND vm.recno IN(1,3,4,5)
Verses Found: 1

Comment: The last thing I can say is the `.` in the pattern matches any char, not just a dot.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying but if I use another character, I get expected results:
SELECT DISTINCT vm.volume_name,vm.recno AS vmid,bk.book_name,bk.recno AS bid,vs.recno,vs.chapter,vs.verse,vs.text FROM verses vs LEFT JOIN books bk ON bk.recno=vs.book LEFT JOIN volumes vm ON bk.volumeid=vm.recno WHERE vs.text regexp "(^|[[:space:]])jesus wept>([[:space:]]|$)" AND vm.recno IN(1,3,4,5)
Verses Found: 0

Comment: I mean, if you need to find a dot, you need to escape it. `"(^|[[:space:]])jesus wept\\.([[:space:]]|$)"`

Comment: I need to ignore the dot and find only the word. The dot is irrelevant to the search.